# Remove all double quotes between double quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I want to remove all double quotes using regex in CSV file if its coming between double quotes. Currently I am using following regex to do this :

```
inputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"([^\^,\r\n])""([^$,\r\n])", @"");
```

But it doesn't work if I have more than two double quotes, for ex:

`"This is my "test" string"` (works)
`"This "is" my "test" string"` (doesn't work)
`"This is" my test string"` (doesn't work)

I need a generic regex which can just remove any double quotes between double quotes in csv file.

Comment: Why not just do `string.Replace("\"", "")` and wrap in quotes? Are there cases where this won't be the format?

Comment: It is ok in case of simple string but in case of csv I have to keep leading and trailing double quotes.

Comment: `1. Remove all quotes 
    2. Put a leading quote
    3. Put a trailing quote`

This is what Grant Thomas is trying to say.

Comment: Tony the Pony, he comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
inputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"([^\^,\r\n])""(?=[^$,\r\n])", @"$1");
```

Comment: Thanks for your regex but it doesn't work for "This is"" my test string""" and results in to :

"This is" my test string"" which is not correct

Comment: it results: "increased Likes"...? it means you may have mutiple matches in the csv. use: Regex reg = new Regex(@"([^\^,\r\n])""(?=[^$,\r\n])", RegexOptions.Multiline); inputString = reg.Replace(inputString, @"$1");

Comment: I tried your suggestion using

Regex reg = new Regex(@"([^\^,\r\n])""(?=[^$,\r\n])", RegexOptions.Multiline); inputString = reg.Replace(inputString, @"$1"); 

but still not desired result,

"This is"" my test string""" results in to : "This is" my test string""

Comment: I see what you want to do, use this: Regex reg = new Regex(@"([^\^,\r\n])""+(?=[^$,\r\n])", RegexOptions.Multiline);            inputString = reg.Replace(inputString, @"$1");

add a + to ""

Answer (score 3):

In a comment my suggestion was: Why not just do `string.Replace("\"", "")` and wrap in quotes? Are there cases where this won't be the format? To which you replied that you need to final string to be enclosed in quotes itself.

Let me try and be more explicit and clear because this is exactly what I suggested. Just do something like:

```
inputString = "\"" + inputString.Replace("\"", "") + "\"";
```

This will remove all quotes, then wrap the end result in the needed quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your regex but it doesn't work for "This "is" my "test" string" and results in to :

"Increased Likes" and comments."" which is not correct

Sorry not for you.

Comment: @SanjaySen I can't make any sense of your comment.

Comment: I think what he wants to do is for a CSV file which may have multiple lines and he wants to keep the " for each line (if exists), AND he does not want to read the txt line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
inputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"(?<=\".*)\"(?=.*\")", @"");
```